# Creating user profile pages in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

What I'm trying to achieve is to make each user on the website(the wp-users) have their own unique front-end profile pages like so `site.com/user/userX`. (EDIT: To clarify, it is not a settings page that only the user himself can see, it's a open profile page for logged users or anonymous/visitors to access and see its profile)

I thought about using the `url GET (site.com/user?name=userX)` in a post but wordpress doesn't seems to understand `"?..=.."` and says page doesn't exist. This solution does not look like a good practice in wordpress so I'm trying to look from another perspective.

Even tho there are a couple of plugins there that would do that for me and more, I'm stuck with doing manually since I'm building a multi-language website (using Polylang), so plugins will only work in the main language.
Briefly, Polylang keeps track of the language through url, ex.: `site.com/langX/pageX`, and the plugins I've tried are stuck to one page only.

I'm inclined to say what I'm looking for is a way in the `functions.php` to make Wordpress understand that a page `.../user/` will expect a name right after `.../user/userX` like that I can use the same function for multiple languages : `...langX/user/userX`, `...langY/user/userX` ...

I'd be glad if someone could put me in the right direction of what should I be looking for.

Comment: Found the answer in another post, routing : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58683/how-to-create-a-front-end-user-profile-with-a-friendly-permalink

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, what you can try is to create a page from dashboard, named user or something. Once users are logged in, you can get user info in session or you can use the query vars as you mentioned above. You can create custom page templates in Wordpress and assign that template to the page. In this page template write the frontend html-s with required logic. Routing in WordPress is normally handled by WordPress itself. So creating a page will make that route say `yoursite.com/user` available for you. Please read on page templates from the below link from WordPress documentation.

https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/

**UPDATED ANSWER**
As per the comments

1. Create a custom post type which holds the data(users)
2. When a user registers, create the entry for users post type, link user id to that post type entry with a post meta. You can set a unique url for the user by setting the slug as you need.
3. Provide users the ability to edit only their own data. You can check the post meta which connects user id with that particular custom post type item.
4. If a user gets removed, delete their custom post type entry as well, so that nothing remains in the DB related to the user.

Comment: As I've said in my question, it's a front-end access, so logged users and anonymous ones are able to view it. I can't possibly create a page for each user that registers on my website, I want to be able to have an url for each user registered, so then I can build a template to display information.

Comment: From where the data comes for anonymous users?. You don't have to create page for each user's. You can use the same page which show the correct info based upon the logged in user's in case of registered user's.

Comment: It's not the users self-page. As the title expresses, I want users to have profile pages. So anyone can see it. (for exemple, what I'm doing, people can create accounts and post information, and the author needs it's own page that could display a variety of information like name, age, biography ... )

Comment: Then the best option will be to create a custom post type say users. which will create an entry for each users when they register. After registration trigger the `wp_insert_post` with the custom post type which will save the entry for that. I don't know any other way it is possible. If this is acceptable I can update my answer with relevant info.

Comment: I thought of that but, for example, I'd need to implement code to to insert, update and/or delete the post each time a user changes it. Also I'd have redundancy in the database, and that could be potential messy and hard to maintain. I'm pretty sure there is a proper way to achieve that, if plugins manage to do it I should be able to... I'm diving into a couple of plugins codes and documentation trying to puzzle out how they make wordpress understand this sort of 'phantom page', but nothing so far.

Comment: if you use only WordPress functions to save remove and connect everything works correctly. If you are planning to query manually you have to manage everything. If you use a framework it is better to use it's own inbuilt method.

Answer (score 0):

for security you should create a new route in wordpress :

```
function custom_rewrite_basic() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^user/([0-9]+)/?', 'index.php?user_profile=$matches[1]', 'top');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_basic');


function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%user_profile%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);
```

Now, you can access the same page as : 
http://example.com/user/95

this code in your theme :

```
get_header(); 
global $wp_query;
if($wp_query->query_vars['user_profile']) {

//do stuff

}
```

Comment: Thanks, the route/routing is what I was looking for. even tho is a bit more complex than you posted, I found a complete explanation and more ways to acheive it! [stack exchange answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/58683/how-to-create-a-front-end-user-profile-with-a-friendly-permalink)